# jqgrid formatting based on certain value. spring jqgrid

Tags: spring, jqgrid

I am new to the JQGRID, I need to format jqgrid based on certain values, lets say if the "NAME" column contains value of "HEMA" and "RAJU" then their respective row should contain the value of n/a (meaning their gender, mobile, location , country should be n/a). I am stuck as I could not figure out how to approach this problem in jqgrid. Guidance will be highly appreciated. I have attached image for clear explanation.

I did some searching but could not find anything closest I could find was formatter but did not work.

```js
var url = "test/gridresult";
$(function(){
("#result").jqGrid({
    url:url,
 datatype: "jsonstring",
        multiselect:false,
    colNames:['Id','NAME', 'GENDER', 'MOBILE','LOCATION','COUNTRY'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', resizable:true},
     {name:'name',index:'name', resizable:true},
     {name:'mobile',index:'mobile', resizable:true},
     {name:'country',index:'country', resizable:true},
       
    ],
    rowNum:100,
    pager: '#prowed1',
sortname: 'id',
    loadonce: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
 jsonReader;{

            repeatitem:false,
            root:"rows",
            page:"page",
            records:"records",
            cell:""
}
});
});


this seems working, I am getting name from loop but how do I set n/a in a row for that particular name
    var rows = $("#result").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
           for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
           {
               var status = $("#resultTable2").getCell(rows[i],"NAME");
               alert("initial value "+status);
               if(status == "HEMA")
               {
                
                   //need to set value of n/a for row that belongs to HEMA   
               }
           }


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

[demo pic for my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J98ms.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I was able to fix it using formatter. Spent good amount of time and finally got it fixed.

```js
function valFormat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
 var  val;
if(rowObject.name=='HEMA' ){
val='N/A';
}else{
val=cellvalue;
}
return val;
}


and in the jqgrid:
{name:'name',index:'name', resizable:true, formatter:valFormat},
```